# Subset data frame based on vector sequence of minimum 5 consecutive values

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, subset

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
out1[1:200]
  [1] NA NA NA NA  0  1  2 NA NA NA  1 NA  0 NA  0  1 NA NA  0 NA  0  1  2  2  2 NA  0  1  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  9  9  9  9
 [41] 10 11 NA  0  0 NA  1 NA  0  1 NA  0 NA  0  1  2 NA  1 NA  0  0  0  1  2 NA NA NA  0  0 NA  0  0  0  1  2 NA  1  2 NA  0
 [81]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 NA  0  1  2  3  4 NA  0  1  2  2  3  4  5 NA  0  1  2  3  3  4  5  5  6  7 NA  1  2 NA  1  2 NA
[121]  0  1  2 NA  1  2  3  3  3  3  4 NA  0  0  0  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA  0  1 NA NA NA  1  2  2  3 NA  1  2  2  2 NA NA  0  1
[161] NA  1 NA  1  2 NA  0  0 NA NA  0  1 NA NA NA NA  1  2  3 NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  6  7  8 NA  0  1
```

I now want to subset a `df` (with the same length) by this vector, but only sequences that have a range over minimum 5 consecutive numbers, e.g. 0:4, or 1:5 (and of course everything longer than this). Hence, `NA`'s should be `FALSE` as well.

E.g.

```
out1: NA NA 0 1 2 2 NA 0 0 1 2 3 3 4 NA
```

Then the result should be

```
out2: F F F F F F F T T T T T T T F
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following gives the desired result

```
library(data.table) # v >= 1.9.5 (devel version - install from GitHub)
data.table(x)[,id:=rleid(!is.na(x)),
   ][ , aa:=(.N>5) , by = id
      ][ ,aaa:=4 %in% cumsum(diff(unique(sort(x)))), by = .(id, aa)
         ]$aaa

## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [15]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

**data**

```
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 2, NA, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, NA, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, NA)
```

Comment: I get an error saying R can't find the rleid function? `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rleid"`

Comment: @Pat You need data.table devel version from github. Install it as `devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)`

Comment: I get another `Error in `[.data.table`(data.table(out1)[, `:=`(id, rleid(!is.na(out1))),  : 
  object 'CisOrderedSubset' not found`

Comment: @Pat How about `as.data.table(x=out1)[,id:=rleid(!is.na(x)),]`

Comment: new error `Error in point(vector("list", length(nz)), seq_along(nz), x, nz) : 
  object 'CpointWrapper' not found`

Comment: What does `str(out1)` say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75397/discussion-between-pat-and-khashaa).

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
x = c(NA,NA,0,1,2,2,NA,0,0,1,2,3,3,4,NA)

with(rle(!is.na(x)), rep(lengths>5, lengths)) & !is.na(x)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

**Other example and results:**

```
x = c(NA, NA, 0, 1, 2, 2, NA, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

x = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,1,NA)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Does it work for `x <- c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, NA)`?

Comment: `[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE`

Comment: But it doesn't contain 5 consecutive numbers. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: How does it "range over minimum 5 consecutive numbers"?

Comment: You are wrong ..when there is 5 or more numbers consecutively return True. Otherwise, return False. This is clearly explained by the OP

Comment: "5 consecutive numbers" means `n:(4+n)`, no?

Comment: `5 or more`. I may write in Chinese next time :)

Comment: As @Khashaa already noticed, I meant something different, 5 consecutive numbers as in 0,1,2,3,4 and not 0,1,2,2,3 the latter one should be `FALSE`

Comment: yes but `x <- c(NA, 0, 0, 1, 2,2,3, NA, 0,1,2,3, NA,1,2,3,3,3,3, NA, 0,1,2,3,4)` will be  `[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[21] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE` . The only `TRUE`s here should be the last 5 numbers